# Trouble plotting and exploring with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm new to using GeoPandas and am trying to follow this [introduction](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction.html). When first trying the code:

```
path_to_data = gpd.datasets.get_path("nybb") 
gdf = gpd.read_file(path_to_data)
gdf = gdf.set_index("BoroName")
gdf["area"] = gdf.area
gdf['boundary'] = gdf.boundary
gdf['centroid'] = gdf.centroid
first_point = gdf['centroid'].iloc[0]
gdf.plot(column="area", legend=True)
gdf.explore("area", legend=False)
```

I got the following error: raise DataDirError(
pyproj.exceptions.DataDirError: Valid PROJ data directory not found. Either set the path using the environmental variable PROJ_LIB or with `pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`

**I tried:**
In terminal:
`set PROJ_LIB=["C:/Users/anaconda3/envs/heck/Library/share/proj"]`

and in Python file:

```
pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir("C:/Users/anaconda3/envs/heck/Library/share/proj")
```

and endet up with just a warning: `UserWarning:  Valid PROJ data directory not found. Either set the path using the environmental variable PROJ_LIB or with` pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`. warnings.warn(str(err))`

I figured I could try to move onwards, but got the following error when using gdf.explore()

```
pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Moreover, I would like to use GeoPandas to differentiate between land and sea, and saw that the Polygons in "nybb" were quite naise. So I'm wondering if it is possible to use these boundaries to  define land also in Europe?